# Socket connection in a API route controller retains the data of previous call

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, socket.io

I have an API endpoint in my Node/Express app. The endpoint is responsible to upload files. There are several stages involved in the upload process. like image conversion, sending images to another third party API, etc. I am using socket.io to tell the client about the current stage of upload.

The problem is, The socket connection works fine in the first call, but in my second call to the endpoint, the socket connection runs twice and retains the data which I sent in the previous call.

Here's my code:

**server.js**

```
import ClientsRouter from './api/routes/clients';
import express from 'express';
import http from 'http';
import io from 'socket.io';

const port  = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const app = express();
const server = http.Server(app);
const socket = io(server);

app.set('socket', socket);

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static('dist'))
app.use('/uploads', express.static('uploads'));


app.use('/api/clients', ClientsRouter);

server.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server Listening on ${process.env.URL}`));
```

**api/routes/clients.js**

```
import express from 'express';
import ClientsController from '../controllers/clients';

ClientsRouter.post('/uploadClientData/', clientDataUpload.array('client_data'), ClientsController.uploadClientData);
```

**controllers/clients.js**

```
const uploadClientData = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const files = req.files
        const clientFolder = req.body.client_folder
        const { dbxUser } = req;
        const team_member_id = req.body.team_member_id;
        const data = req.files.map( i => ({team_member_id, destination: i.destination.substring(1), filename: i.filename, status: 1 } ))
        const io = req.app.get("socket");
        console.log("Outside Socket", data);  //This contains my currently passed data
        io.on('connection', async socket => {
            console.log("Socket Connection established");
            console.log("Inside Socket", data);  //But This contains my current data aling with the data that I passed in previous call
            await uploadQueue.collection.insertMany(data)
            socket.emit('upload stage', { upload_stage: 2, progress: 33 })
            await helpers.convertImagesToWebResolution(team_member_id, req.body.dpi, req.body.resolution);
            socket.emit('upload stage', { upload_stage: 3, progress: 66 })
            await helpers.uploadImagesToDropbox(team_member_id, dbxUser, clientFolder)
            socket.emit('upload stage', { upload_stage: 4, progress: 100 })
        })

        res.status(200).json({message: "Uploaded"});

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        res.status(500).json({
            error
        });
    }
}
```

And in my front-end react component

```
componentDidMount(){
    const { currentFolder } = this.props;
    this.setState({ client_folder: currentFolder }, () => this.afterFileSelect())
}



componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
    const { selectedFiles } = this.props;
    if(prevProps.selectedFiles !== selectedFiles){
        this.afterFileSelect()
    }
}

afterFileSelect = async () => {
    const { selectedFiles, setSelectedFiles, currentFolder, user, uploadSettings} = this.props;
    let formData = new FormData()
    formData.append('client_folder', currentFolder)
    formData.append('team_member_id', user.team_member_id)
    formData.append('resolution', uploadSettings.resolution.split("x")[0])
    formData.append('dpi', uploadSettings.dpi)
    for(let selectedFile of selectedFiles){
        formData.append('client_data', selectedFile)
    }
    let uploadResp = uploadSettings.convert_web_res ? await uploadClientData(formData) : await dropboxDirectUpload(formData)
    const endpoint = uploadResp.config.url;
    const host = endpoint.substring(0, endpoint.indexOf("api"));
    const socket = socketIOClient(host);
    socket.on("upload stage", data => {
        this.setState({upload_stage: data.upload_stage, progress: data.progress})
        data.upload_stage === 4 && this.setState({client_folder: ""})
    })
}
```

Also I want to know if this is the correct way to to track upload progress?